# How to fetch data using linkedin API ?

Tags: php, api, linkedin-api

Not able to fetch user's full profile data although I have given fullprofile permission in Linkedin API?
i have given r_fullprofile permission to my web app and i am getting full profile data for me but i am not able to fetch the full data of my connections. why is it so? is there any different permissions i have to take for my app?

Answer (score 0):

Linkedin API only allows you to fetch full profile data for your own profile, not for your connection's profiles.